# "The User Profile Service failed the logon” error. No solution working

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, user-profiles

> The User Profile Service failed the logon

error is popping up each time I start my computer (on Windows 7, workgroup environment). Even Safe mode starts with Default Profile

I have tried following (through safe mode)

1. Editing registry as suggested on in [Method 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/947215/you-receive-a-the-user-profile-service-failed-the-logon-error-message)
2. Tried creating a new account, through control panel or command prompt, but not working.
3. Deleted profile as suggested in the 3rd method.
4. Tried recovery options.

Ultimately, also deleted the user profile folder from C:\users, as suggested by some site. Even this didn't work.

What should I do?

Images: [c:\users while showing hidden and system files]

[image]

Edit: I tried enabling administrator account (with command prompt) and thankfully it is starting but with a lot of errors.
Still, unable to create new user with control panel.

While adding user with command prompt, user directories and registry entry are not building up.

Comment: Looks like the problem is that the *Default* user is corrupted. Try this: https://www.kapilarya.com/the-user-profile-service-failed-the-sign-in-windows-10

Comment: @iTechieGamer I don't have any usable user profile. When I use 'Default user' it produces an error

Comment: The *Default user* is a [junction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx) to the *Default* folder. Because you don't have any usable user profile, you can try this: https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/67875-corrupt-ntuser-dat-file-default-folder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit these pages, step-wise (i.e., if first don't work then try second)

1) https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/947215

2) https://superuser.com/a/1298468/822976

3) https://www.kapilarya.com/the-user-profile-service-failed-the-sign-in-windows-10

4) https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/67875-corrupt-ntuser-dat-file-default-folder.html (Try all solutions available here)

5) a) Try downloading Windows .iso file, newer than installed (not necessary for this step, but if it didn't work, same .iso file can be used in next step) and of **same version** as installed (important).

b) Mount to USB drive using Rufus (from https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

c) Boot through USB

d) Try the recovery options.

6)  Use the same .iso file (from step 5) And **upgrade** your windows (don't select 'clean install').

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:
https://web.archive.org/web/20111106031316/http://rob.brooks-bilson.com/index.cfm/2009/1/5/Fix-for-Vistas-The-User-Profile-Service-service-failed-the-logon-User-profile-cannot-be-loaded

> [...]
>
> there are two directories preventing the default profile from being created. The first is:
>
> c:\users\default\AppData\Local\Application Data
>
> [...] the root Application Data folder contains a lot of recursively added \Application Data folders. My best guess is that something went wrong during one of the Windows update processes, resulting in all of the extra recursive \Application Data directories. From the research I've done this doesn't appear to be limited to a single specific Windows update as people have reported the problem as far back as 2007.
>
> The second directory you'll need to take a look at is:
>
> C:\users\default\Local Settings\Application Data
>
> Again, if you look in this directory you should find several more levels of \Application Data appended to the top level \Application Data:
>
> In both cases, what you'll need to do is to delete all of the additional occurrences of \Application Data below the root level. Once you've done this any user experiencing the "The User Profile Service service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded" error should be able to login.

Comment: C:\users\default\Local Settings, c:\users\default\AppData\Local are not present there

Comment: yes, my problem is user directories are not building, as I added new user with command prompt.

Comment: How many folders are counted in the properties of the _Default_ folder? Mine, for example, has 200.